# Google Fusion Table Layer turned off by default

Tags: toggle, google-fusion-tables, layer

Stackoverflow is a very stunning site!!! I learn a lot here,

Now I'm try to do something nice for my comunity: a gmaps v3 with some fusion table and some custom base map...

I'm looking at this xample: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_toggle.html.
I want the layers are turned off at load page: any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Andrea

Comment: What have you tried?  The general answer is change the code to do that. Uncheck the boxes, don't set the map property of the layers.

Comment: thanks for fast replay, I tray to put unchek box but they respond in inverse way: if the checkbox is unselected the layer is visible and if the chak box is selected the lier is unvsible, that dont solv my problem... i think the problem is in that string:     function toggleLayer(this_layer){
      if(this_layer.getMap()) {
        this_layer.setMap(null)
      } else {
        this_layer.setMap(map);
      }
    }
   var layer1=null;
   var layer2=null;
   var map=null;

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the boxes:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer1" onchange="toggleLayer(layer1)"/>
  <label> old boundaries </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer2" onchange="toggleLayer(layer2)"/>
  <label> new boundaries </label>
```

Don't set the map property of the layers:

```
  layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'col2',
      from:'1NxFkNmdXHOvvWNnaWscabdxUDQqDul1BpiINtHI'
    }
  });
  layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'col2',
      from:'1aM37b7PzUg3nqF14L4GzDbSrUGAfWOuIGcbkV2c'
    }
  });
```

Comment: work fine... many thanks very much... actually I have to study much the code and how does it work...